# botframework node.js bot does not connect to chatconnector

Tags: node.js, botframework

So when I tried to connect my microsoft bot written in node.js (using LUIS as the intent recognizer) to azure bot, it doesn't connect. But it runs fine locally using the emulator and the version written in .NET connects fine as well. What could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: When you say "I tried to connect my microsoft bot to ... azure bot" -- What do you mean by "azure bot"?